# How to Bind Property from one component to App.Component in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

test.component.html

```
<input type="text" name="fname" [(ngModel)]="user">
<button
class="btn btn-primary">Update Server</button>
```

test.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testcomp',
  styleUrls: ['./testcomp.component.css']
})
export class TestcompComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  @Input() user:any;
  ngOnInit() {

  }


}
```

In the app.component.html

```
<app-testcomp [user]="ide"></app-testcomp>
<button
(click)="onserclicked()">Clicked</button>
```

In its ts file

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  ide:any;

  onserclicked()
  {
    alert(this.ide)
  }
}
```

On clicking the button in the app.component.html...it is showing undefined rather than the value which was entered in the text box in the user-component

Comment: you need to use `@Output` decorator instead of input and use an event emitter in TestcompComponent to emit the value which was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Comment is right, but u can use other stuff to achieve it.
Delete this input that actually don't needed, leave just

```
user:any;
```

Name your component like

```
<app-testcomp #testcomp></app-testcomp>
<button (click)="onserclicked(testcomp.user)">Clicked</button>
```

and then all will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the decorator **@Output** :

**app.component.html :**

```
<app-testcomp [user]="ide" (userClick)="onserclicked($event)"></app-testcomp>
<button
(click)="onserclicked()">Clicked</button>
```

**test.component.html**

```
<input type="text" name="fname" [(ngModel)]="user">
<button
class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onChange()">Update Server</button>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testcomp',
  styleUrls: ['./testcomp.component.css']
})
export class TestcompComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  @Input() user:any;

  @Output()
  userClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public onChange(){
      this.change.emit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


}
```

You could try this. It's working, I guess.

You could [this tutorial by Todd Motto](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2) to understand all of component events